# Flutter: Future.wait does not seem to work

Tags: flutter, firebase, future

I build a widget on my front page which relies on information I receive from Firebase.

Because this widget can not display properly without the information from the database (dates, picture URLs, etc.), there are two futures that have to be completed (to fetch the data from the database) before this widget can be rendered.

Right now, I call a function from my frontpage's setState method which calls an async function `getAllFutures()` in which I execute the following code:

```
await Future.wait([
  globals.checkExistingWochenplan(),
  globals.getWochenplan(kw: 34)
]).then((value) {
  print(value);
  print("DONE");
});
```

From what I understood about `Future.wait` (correct me if I am wrong), this method, when executed, blocks the main thread until all futures are completed, which is exactly what I want, because I rely on the data. Is that right? Because, when I check out my debug console messages, the rest of my app keeps executing while the futures in `Future.wait` get executed.

What am I doing wrong here/whether I use `Future.wait` correctly or not?

The print statement in the `.then` method afterward returns `null` twice btw, but that is probably because of the futures themselves.

### Edit

As wished, here are the two functions `Future.wait` executes:

globals.checkExistingWochenplan()

- This function makes a database call and checks weather or not there ARE mealplans (gonna translate it to english for you since the function is half english half german) right now.

```
Future checkExistingWochenplan() async {
  print("-> checkExistingWochenplan() Start <-");

  return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection("einstellungen")
  .where("id", isEqualTo: "s5RFWJpf6cZHjshHE5HdVDjKBQe2")
  .get()
  .then((snapshot){
    for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {

      print("1") ;

      Map dbMap = doc["wochenplaene"];

      print("dbMap");
      print(dbMap);
      
      dbMap.forEach((key, value) {
        kwsWochenplaeneMap.addAll({
          key: value
        });

        if(!kwsWochenplaeneNummern.contains(int.parse(key))){
          kwsWochenplaeneNummern.add(int.parse(key));
        }
      });
    }

    // TODO: Die Jahre in der DB hinterlegen, damit beim Jahreswechsel nicht falsch sortiert wird
    kwsWochenplaeneMap = Map.fromEntries(
      kwsWochenplaeneMap.entries.toList()..sort((a, b) => a.key.compareTo(b.key))
    );

    kwsWochenplaeneNummern.sort(((a, b) => b.compareTo(a)));

    print("kwsWochenplaeneNummern");
    print(kwsWochenplaeneNummern);

    print("2");
  });
}
```

After that (I just noticed there is no condition yet, so the db call would happen either way), I fetch the mealplans data for the current week (because the last build worked in calender week 34, I manually set the calender week to 34 which is fine year, I already got a function that calculates the actual current week number).

globals.getWochenplan(kw: 34)

This function retrievs the data from the mealplan with the calender number `kw` that I pass to this function (right now alot of print tastements to test the call order).

```
Future getWochenplan({int kw = 34}) async {
    print("-> getWochenplan() <-");

    print("Wochenplan");
    print(globals.wochenplanTag);

    print("kw");
    print(kw);
    print("asdsadsadsad");

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("wochenplan")
    .where("id", isEqualTo: "s5RFWJpf6cZHjshHE5HdVDjKBQe2")
    .where("kw", isEqualTo: 34)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot){
      print("hiiiiiiiier");

      for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
        print("A");
        print(globals.wochenplanTag);

        //if(globals.wochenplanTag.isEmpty){

          globals.wochenplanAktivesGericht = doc.data()["aktiveGerichte"];

          globals.wochenplanMoeglicheGerichte = doc.data()["moeglicheGerichte"];

          for (int i = 0; i < globals.wochenplanAktivesGericht.length; i++){
            globals.allePageViewController.add(
              PageController(initialPage: globals.wochenplanAktivesGericht[i], keepPage: false)
            );
          }

          for (int i = 0; i < globals.wochenplanAktivesGericht.length; i++){
            // TODO: Hier muss dann die tatsächliche Anzahl an Alternativen rein
            // TODO: Wird die tatsächliche Anzahl an Alternativen schon in die DB gepusht?

            for (int k = 0; k < globals.wochenplanMoeglicheGerichte; k++){
              wochenplanListMap.add({
                "datum": doc.data()["KW $kw"]["${i+1}. ${wochentage[i]}"][k]["datum"].toString(),
                "img": doc.data()["KW $kw"]["${i+1}. ${wochentage[i]}"][k]["img"],
                "naehrwertKalorien": doc.data()["KW $kw"]["${i+1}. ${wochentage[i]}"][k]["naehrwertKalorien"],
                "naehrwertKohlenhydrate": doc.data()["KW $kw"]["${i+1}. ${wochentage[i]}"][k]["naehrwertKohlenhydrate"],
                "naehrwertFett": doc.data()["KW $kw"]["${i+1}. ${wochentage[i]}"][k]["naehrwertFett"],
                "naehrwertEiweiss": doc.data()["KW $kw"]["${i+1}. ${wochentage[i]}"][k]["naehrwertEiweiss"],
                "naehrwertBallaststoffe": doc.data()["KW $kw"]["${i+1}. ${wochentage[i]}"][k]["naehrwertBallaststoffe"],
                "naehrwerte": [doc.data()["KW $kw"]["${i+1}. ${wochentage[i]}"][k]["naehrwertKalorien"], doc.data()["KW $kw"]["${i+1}. ${wochentage[i]}"][k]["naehrwertKohlenhydrate"], doc.data()["KW $kw"]["${i+1}. ${wochentage[i]}"][k]["naehrwertFett"], doc.data()["KW $kw"]["${i+1}. ${wochentage[i]}"][k]["naehrwertEiweiss"]],
                "zutaten": doc.data()["KW $kw"]["${i+1}. ${wochentage[i]}"][k]["zutaten"]
              });

              print(">>> nach List Map");

              // gesamtXYZ NUR erhöhen, wenn es sich um das aktuell aktive Gericht aus dem Wochenplan handelt
              if(k == globals.wochenplanAktivesGericht[i]){
                globals.gesamtKalorien = globals.gesamtKalorien + int.parse(doc.data()["KW $kw"]["${i+1}. ${wochentage[i]}"][k]["naehrwertKalorien"].toString());
                globals.gesamtKohlenhydrate = globals.gesamtKohlenhydrate + int.parse(doc.data()["KW $kw"]["${i+1}. ${wochentage[i]}"][k]["naehrwertKohlenhydrate"].toString());
                globals.gesamtFett = globals.gesamtFett + int.parse(doc.data()["KW $kw"]["${i+1}. ${wochentage[i]}"][k]["naehrwertFett"].toString());
                globals.gesamtEiweiss = globals.gesamtEiweiss + int.parse(doc.data()["KW $kw"]["${i+1}. ${wochentage[i]}"][k]["naehrwertEiweiss"].toString());
                globals.gesamtBallaststoffe = globals.gesamtBallaststoffe + int.parse(doc.data()["KW $kw"]["${i+1}. ${wochentage[i]}"][k]["naehrwertBallaststoffe"].toString());
              }
            }

            globals.wochenplanTag.add(wochenplanListMap);

            wochenplanListMap = [];
          }

          (doc.data()["zutatenAufEinkaufsliste"] == null) ? globals.zutatenAufEinkaufsliste = false : globals.zutatenAufEinkaufsliste = doc.data()["zutatenAufEinkaufsliste"];
        //}
      }
    });
  }
```

So as I said, I have a widget on my front page which shows the mealplan of the current week and I have to pass the information from the database to this widget.

I will/want to work with local storage so that this information does not have to be retrieved everytime, but that is still on my last.

For now, I would just like to wait until these two Futures are done, so that I can use their data.

The condition to display my image etc. lateron looks like this:

"If the list with the calender numbers of available mealplans CONTAIS the current calender week" then I show the mealplan widget, otherwise I show a fallback.

```
if(globals.kwsWochenplaeneNummern.contains(globals.aktuelleKW)){
```

Comment: are you returning a result in the methods checkExistingWochenplan() and getWochenplan()?

Comment: First off: don't combine `await` and `then` in a single code block please. Use one or the other. --- Second: it's hard to say what's going on here since we can't see your `checkExistingWochenplan` and `getWochenplan` functions. Can you [reproduce the problem in a single, standalone block of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful) so that we can all look at the same, full context?

Comment: `await` doesn't block threads. The whole point of futures is to avoid blocking threads, and  `await` is just syntactic sugar around continuation passing with `then()`. Basically, `var x = await f; doSomethingWith(x);` is equivalent to `f.then((x) { doSomethingWith(x)}`;

I agree with @FrankvanPuffelen that to answer this question properly more context is needed. Whatever operations are happening in parallel with the `await` statement must be part of a different function.

Comment: I just edited my post with the contents of the functions. I just did not post them up front because that makes the post pretty long.

Answer (score 1):

The `Future.wait()` is used to wait for multiple futures to complete and collects their results. Returns a future which will complete once all the provided futures have completed, either with their results, or with an error if any of the provided futures fail. But you shouldn't mix `then` and `await`, it's better for consistency to use either/or. For example:

```
 void main()  {
 Future.wait([delayedNumber(), delayedString()])
 .then((value) {
  print(value);
  print("DONE");
});
   print("printed first outside of future");
}


Future<int> delayedNumber() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  return 2;
}

Future<String> delayedString() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  return "result";
}
```

which would give you:

```
printed first outside of future
[2, result]
DONE
```

While if you use `async/await`:

```
 void main() async {
 var value = await Future.wait([delayedNumber(), delayedString()]);
 print(value);
 print("printed at the end");
}


Future<int> delayedNumber() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  return 2;
}

Future<String> delayedString() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  return "result";
}
```

You would get the following:

```
[2, result]
printed at the end
```

You can read more about it here:

[Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://%5Bhttps://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await%5D)

[wait static method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/wait.html)

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question. It's fair to say that it's better to commit to one paradigm or the other, mixing `await` and `then` by itself doesn't cause the problem the OP observed.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong. Future.wait does not block the main thread, in fact, there is nothing called main thread in Dart. Dart is single threaded, which means it uses an event loop. That's why your app keeps working during an awaited Future.

```
this.isLoading = true;
setState(() {});
final value = await Future.wait([
  globals.checkExistingWochenplan(),
  globals.getWochenplan(kw: 34)
]);
this.isLoading = false;
this.image = value.first;
this.dates = value.last;
setState(() {});
```

One approach (amongst many others) to use data from Future in UI is to use flags like `isLoading` above and display the widget that require the data once the flag is toggled.

Somewhere in your build tree, you should have something like (pseudocode)

```
 (isLoading) ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Container(child: Image(image: this.image))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! Understood. I think it would look a little odd though, if there is no mealplan (what the futures retrive) and after a few seconds, it is suddenly there and pushes the rest of my widgets down. Thats why I would like to wait for there futures to complete BEFORE I continue with the rest of the code. That is just for testing though. In the release, I will work with local storage so that retriving the data from firebase is not going to be needed everytime.

Is there no way in flutter to wait for futures to complete and THEN go on with the app? Or is this just wrong?

Comment: You can do that by calling your futures before runApp in the void main function, so changing it to Future<void> main, use async await, not then.  but that's not a common approach. People usually call futures in widget init state methods and show Loading UI like in my answer. But if this approach works for you, that's how we do it